# Change "Shipping & Handling" text in checkout review

Tags: magento

I need to change the "Shipping & Handling" text in the last step of the onepage checkout on magento, but I can't find it in any template .phtml file.

Is there anybody that had the same issue and knows what file I need to edit?

Answer (score 6):

Ok I got it myself, you need to edit or overwrite with a custom extension the following file: "app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Shipping.php"

around line 184 (Magento 1.7.0.2) you'll find the method "fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)" here you'll find "Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping & Handling');".

Answer (score 0):

magento\app\locale\en_US  this folder has CSV files for English US  here you can define your language translates.
File  Mage_Sales.csv  has the value you want to modify.